# how to pass value in angular js in jsp/servlet

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I am developing a module in jsp/servlet in which i need to use angular js.
how could i pass the value from input box value in function then 
how to send value in servlet also...!

Here the example of code:-

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="mehandi" >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js">  
     </script>
     <script>
        var app = angular.module('mehandi', []);
        app.controller('mhndiCtrl', function($http){
            var xyz = this;
            xyz.data = {}
            xyz.swati = function($http){


            }

        })


    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mhndiCtrl as abc" >
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="abc.data.myname">
    {{abc.data}}
    <button ng-click="abc.swati()" > </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the function via `ng-init`:  in your html

```
ng-init="init('${userDTO.username}')"
```

So, in your *.js ng-controller it will be following:

```
$scope.init = function(username){
   /*logic code*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the name attribute of input for servlets

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

You can then retrieve it using

```
request.getParameter("firstname")
```

The angular part remains the same

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="abc.data.myname">
```

Remember, angularjs is a client side javascript framework, hence server side bindings remains the same.

Comment: how can i send Data from inputbox to angular js and then send servlet to save data in database please explain

Comment: for angularjs has two way binding ... http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/ and in servlet once you get the value using getParameter you can put into database